# Comparing CString to TCHAR by ==?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, string-comparison, tchar

I have a CString pointer and it is being compared to a TCHAR in the following way:

```
if(srtTest[i] == _T('\n'))
  //do something
```

where strTest is a  CString* strTest;

I just wonder if this is correct, considering it is not a TCHAR-pointer. It compiles ok.
This code is very old and no one seems to have complained about it, makes me wonder though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's ok (assuming `strTest` is a valid pointer and `i` is a valid index). Since `strTest` is a `CString*`, `strTest[i]` is a `CString`. And there is a free `operator==` overload that accepts a `const CString&` as param1 and an `LPCTSTR` as param2 and then does what you'd expect.

The MSDN documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315046(v=vs.60).aspx). The second overload is the one that matters:

```
BOOL operator ==( const CString& s1, LPCTSTR s2 );
```

(the documentation is out of date and the signature I see when I trace into the actual code is different, but the effect is the same)

MarkRansom alerted me to the fact that your code compares `strTest[i]` to a character rather than to a string. That's still ok, because there is also an `operator==` overload that takes `CString`/`char`. It's not listed in the documentation I linked to, but here's what the actual code looks like in the VS2012 version:

```
friend bool operator==(
        _In_ const CStringT& str1,
        _In_ XCHAR ch2) throw()
    {
        return( (str1.GetLength() == 1) && (str1[0] == ch2) );
    }
```

Since it's not listed in the outdated documentation, this function presumably did not always exist. However, `CString` has an implicit constructor that takes a `TCHAR`. I assume that in VC++ versions that predate the above, a `CString` would be implicitly constructed from `_T('\n')` and then used in a call to the `CString`/`CString` overload of `operator==`.

Comment: Those are single quotes around the literal, not double quotes, so it's a `TCHAR` and not a `LPCTSTR`.

Comment: @MarkRansom True. I'm not sure if that's a typo or not, but I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, in the real code there are single quotes. I just got a bit confused, ut now it seems to have cleared up! :)

Answer (score 2):

[The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315046(v=vs.60).aspx) on CString operators is old. Very old. They do provide `operator==` for `LPCTSTR`, but that is defined as a `const TCHAR*`. `_T('\n')` is a `TCHAR`, not a `TCHAR*` so none of these apply. Yet it seems to work...

In cstringt.h, I see (I'm using VS 2010):

```
friend bool operator==(
    _In_ const CStringT& str1,
    _In_ XCHAR ch2) throw()
{
    return( (str1.GetLength() == 1) && (str1[0] == ch2) );
}
```

[This article](http://mfctips.com/2011/10/02/tchar-xchar-ychar-explained/) explains simply what an `XCHAR` is. Basically a `TCHAR`. So here, presumably, is the `bool operator==(const CString&, TCHAR ch)` you are using.

Comment: Thank you also for your reply, I think I got it straightened out in my head now!